# How to create a counter in JMeter and save the value for the next execution?

Tags: jmeter

i've been trying to save the value of a counter once the execution finishes, with the idea that the next one starts with that same value. For example: I start with a counter that has 1 as value, loop it 5 times and the execution finishes with that counter having his value in 5. Then, i want that counter to start with his value in 5, how is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

You can save it into a file using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) like:

```
new File('counter.txt').text = vars.get('your-counter-variable-name-here')
```

where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands

the same for initialization, you can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) with the following code:

```
${__groovy(file = new File('counter.txt'); if (file.exists()) {return file.text} else { return '0'},)}
```